# Flutter Build Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: flutter, gradle

After adding "cloud-firestore" to dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file it keeps giving me this error when I try to run the project.

After I tried to remove the addiction and it keeps giving me the same error

Does anyone else face this issue? What causes this? How can I fix/circumvent this?

```
MBP-di-Federico:degustazioni.blog-flutter- federico$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
[string/default_web_client_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/default_web_client_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/firebase_database_url] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/firebase_database_url] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/google_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/google_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/google_app_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/google_app_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/google_crash_reporting_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/google_crash_reporting_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/google_storage_bucket] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/google_storage_bucket] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
[string/project_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/project_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.                   
> [string/default_web_client_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/default_web_client_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/firebase_database_url] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/firebase_database_url] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml   [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/google_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml    [string/google_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/google_app_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/google_app_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/google_crash_reporting_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml    [string/google_crash_reporting_api_key] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/google_storage_bucket] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml [string/google_storage_bucket] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/project_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml    [string/project_id] /Users/federico/Desktop/Develop/Flutter/degustazioni.blog-Flutter-/build/app/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values 2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 4s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         6,7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```